# How do I return customer_id whose first order value > second order value?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as below:

orders: order_id, customer_id, item_price, item_quantity, order_datetime

Now I want to return customer_id whose the first order value is greater than the second one.

Sorry I don't have any code as I have totally no idea how to do this question :(

Answer (score 1):

One option uses window functions and aggregation:

```
select customer_id
from (
    select o.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by oder_datetime) rn
    from orders o
) o
where rn <= 2
group by customer_id
having sum(
    case when rn = 1 
        then   item_price * item_quantity 
        else - item_price * item_quantity 
    end
) > 0
```